# Java - simple json to file (almost complete)

Tags: java, json

I created a simple json object now I want to save it into a file.

```
File file = new File(fileDir + "flow.txt");
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
//JSON Object        
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
  jsonObject.put("name",testCaseName);
  jsonObject.put("type", tf.testCase.getType());
  jsonObject.put("url", url);
  jsonObject.put("ip", container.getNetworkSettings().getNetworks().get("bridge").getIpAddress());
  jsonObject.put("inputs", tf.params.replaceAll(","," "));
```

What now??

Comment: Tired this http://crunchify.com/how-to-write-json-object-to-file-in-java/ , or there https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/read-write-json-using-jackson-objectmapper-jsonparser-jsongenerator-example ?

Comment: FileWriter file = new FileWriter("path_of_file");
file.write(obj.toJSONString());

Comment: what JSON library do you use?

Comment: I dont have toJSONString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FileWriter` and just pass in the `jsonObject`:

```
try {
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
    fileWriter.write(jsonObject.toString());
    fileWriter.flush();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[Source](http://www.websparrow.org/java/how-to-write-json-object-to-file-in-java)

Comment: I dont have toJSONString. Only toJSONArray

Comment: please name extra libaries that you have

Comment: Change to: `jsonObject.toString()`

Comment: use try-with-resources: `try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)) { ... } catch (Exception e) {}`